# c template member variable error

Tags: c++, class, templates

**error: 'TrieNode::parent' has incomplete type**
 How to solve this? Please help me

TrieNode.h

```
    template <typename T>
    class TrieNode {

    public:
        char subStr;
        list<TrieNode> childs;
        TrieNode<T> parent;     // error
```

Comment: you cannot have a `TrieNode` in the `TrieNode` class unless it is a pointer or a reference

Comment: @aaronman, Or a reference.

Comment: @aaronman and chris It doesn't produce any error for me

Comment: @banarun you must be either a god or a moron then

Comment: @aaronman Please try running it. I don't know how, but it doesn't show any error for me.

Comment: @banarun there really isn't a debate here you cannot put a class inside itself as a value

Comment: @banarun You need to instantiate the template, otherwise the compiler will ignore its definition.

Comment: @jogojapan do all compilers ignore it?

Comment: @aaronman Ah... ok, I don't know that. I am just sure that GCC and Clang generally overlook a lot of problems in template definitions until I actually use them, and based on the Standard they have every right to do so.

Comment: @jogojapan sorry it was a question, not acting like I know, good suggestion

Comment: Thanks all. Problem is resolved. change parent to * parent

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want parent to be a pointer to a TrieNode rather than an instance.

```
template <typename T>
class TrieNode {

public:
    char subStr;
    list<TrieNode> childs;
    TrieNode<T> *parent;
    ...
```

As you've currently implemented things a `TrieNode<T>` would contain a char + a list + `TrieNode<T>`, which is to say it would be infinitely large.